# Reset navigation history to Login screen using react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I would like after Login (Welcome) the user to navigate to Home. I reset the history so the user cannot go back like this:

```
const actionToDispatch = NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })]
        });

        this.props.navigation.dispatch(actionToDispatch);
```

This works properly. After pressing Log Out the user should go back to Welcome but **it's not working**. Here's what exactly I am doing:

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Welcome' }),
            ]
        });

        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

The error says that there is no route for 'Welcome'. Must be one of 'Main', 'Privacy', 'Terms' which are routes of one of the tabs in the Home. See them below:

```
 const AppStack = StackNavigator({
                    Welcome: {
                        screen: Welcome
                    },
                    Home: {
                        screen: Tabs
                    }
                }, {
                        initialRouteName: this.state.isLoggedIn ? 'Home' : 'Welcome',
                        headerMode: 'none'
                    }
                );

export const ProfileStack = StackNavigator({
    Profile: {
        screen: Profile,
    },
});

export const SettingsStack = StackNavigator({
    Settings: {
        screen: Settings,
    },
}, {
    });

export const InfoStack = StackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: Main,
    },
    Privacy: {
        screen: Privacy
    },
    Terms: {
        screen: Terms
    }
});

const routeConfiguration = {

    Profile: { screen: ProfileStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack },
    Info: { screen: InfoStack }
};

const tabBarConfiguration = {
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'white',
        inactiveTintColor: 'lightgray',
        labelStyle: {
            fontSize: Normalize(10),
            fontFamily: Fonts.book
        },
        style: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.greenLightGradient,
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            borderTopColor: Colors.tabGreenLine
        },
    }
};

export const Tabs = TabNavigator(routeConfiguration, tabBarConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 15):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/789.

```js
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Welcome' }),
            ],
            key: null
        });

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

**key: null** is the important part.

Comment: I've the same code but it's not working for me. Does this only work on StackNavigator? I'm using the TabNavigator.

Comment: Yes, I think that it's not working for TabNavigator. But you should check again because it was several months ago when I lastly check for this.

Comment: I also found that this doesn't work for me, created a question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575437/react-navigation-preventing-going-back-to-loading-screen?noredirect=1#comment78111975_45575437

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is looking for `React Navigation 3.x and 4.x` solution

```
import {NavigationActions, StackActions} from 'react-navigation';

 const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Home'})],
      key: null,
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

React Navigation move the reset method to `StackActions` since 3.x

Comment: oh yeah, it works for RN 3.x and 4.x! thank you John!

Answer (score 3):

replace home with any screen you want reset history for (v5)

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
  navigation.dispatch(state => {
 // Remove the home route from the stack
 const routes = state.routes.filter(r => r.name !== 'Home');

 return CommonActions.reset({
...state,
routes,
index: routes.length - 1,
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Great way to remove any screen from your nav stack.

Comment: thank you @Richard Bonneau

Answer (score 1):

For those who use **version 5.x**, Ahmed Mersal's solution is perfect.

Starting from that, we can do a reusable React hook:

```
import { useNavigation, CommonActions } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const useRemoveRouteFromState = (
  routeName: keyof ReactNavigation.RootParamList
) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.dispatch((state) => {
      const routes = state.routes.filter(({ name }) => name !== routeName);

      return CommonActions.reset({
        ...state,
        routes,
        index: routes.length - 1,
      });
    });
  }, [navigation]);
};
```

Then, inside a component, we just have to use it:

```
export const PurchaseScreen: React.FC = () => {
  useRemoveRouteFromState('Home');

  // ...
};
```