# How to Disable back swipe option or pop a route in React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a Login Page(StackNavigator) and a Tabbed pages(TabNavigator).

```
export const Root = StackNavigator({
  LoginScreen: {screen: Login},
  Tabs: {screen: Tabs}
},
  {
  initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen'
  }
)
```

After logging the user in there is still a possibility for the user to go back(to Login Page) by swiping back. What is the way of popping the login route from the Route Stack or disabling the back swipe option. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatch a [reset action](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset) instead of the normal navigation dispatch. That way you can set the stack to the state you want it to be after logging in and remove your `LoginScreen` from the stack.

Example related answers:

- [Resetting the navigation stack for the home screen (React Navigation and React Native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090884/resetting-the-navigation-stack-for-the-home-screen-react-navigation-and-react-n)
- [Reset navigation history to Login screen using react navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496739/reset-navigation-history-to-login-screen-using-react-navigation)

Comment: Thanks for great resources, helped out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The official way to handle it from React Navigation (v6) is to define the screens in the navigator based on an `isSignedIn` condition so that the Login screen will not exist within the navigator once the `isSignedIn` variable has been set to `true`.

For example:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  {isSignedIn ? (
    <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabsScreen} />
  ) : (
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
  )}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

See the [Authentication Flows](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) section for more information.