# Is there a way to make unable to navigate back to page in StackNavigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I faced the problem during developing application in React-Native js framework with navigation. I, ve got a StackNavigator, which navigates me between Login and Main pages. But I don't want to make user navigate back to login page, when he either hits phone button, or navigates by button on the bar of screen, without logging out

Is there a way to deny StackNavigator to navigate back to Login page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, once you've ascertained the login is successful, what you need to do is reset the stack via a [Reset Navigation Action.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset)

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile'})
  ]
})

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

with the name of your route, which is I presume is Home or something along those lines.

If you wanted to go back in a log-out state by resetting the whole thing you would have [to pass null to the key param](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43497435/941770).